# How is this change bar made using absolute and relative position?

Tags: css, css-position

```css
p{
position:relative;
margin-right:10px;
left:10px;
}

span{
position:absolute;
top:auto;
left:-1em;
color:red;
}
```

```html
<p>
I used two red hyphens to serve as a change bar. They
will "float" to the left of the line containing at the very least THIS
<span>--</span>word.</p>
```

I found it [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#comp-abspos). It is the example just before Layer Presentation Section.

After some playing with it, I don't even know what this change bar does. It is a span between "THIS" and "word". One thing is clear: it is always gonna on the same line as the word "word". Not necessarily on the last line.

I have 3 questions as to how this change bar is made:

1. In the CSS for p tag. The author of the code says he uses margin-left:10px "in anticipation" of the offset (relative position left:10px). Why in anticipation? Don't the 2 conflict each other?
2. I am not clear where the containing box of the span is, and how POSITION:absolute and LEFT:-1em. POSITION:absolute takes the SPAN out of the normal flow and put in at the top left corner of its containing box, but I don't know where that containing box is. And how LEFT:-1em makes the change bar looks like it's floating to the left. Let's say browser default font is 16px, then 1em will be 16px, so that means LEFT:-1em moves the change bar 16px to the left.

Without LEFT:-1em. It looks like the bar is stuck in the first letter of the first word in the last line.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The p has a margin-right, not margin left. The anticipation sounds like they are making sure there is a gap to the right of the p equal to the gap to the left that it is getting from the position:relative; left:10px declaration (used to make room for the hyphens it seems like).
2. Position absolute takes it out of flow, and top: 0, left: 0, would be the top left corner. So the top: auto is telling it to keep the space from the top that it would naturally have in it's normal flow so wherever the span would fall in the paragraph naturally, it is picking up that height at it's top. The left:-1em just knocks it as you said 16px (if that's the setting) to the left, but the left 0 would be at the left edge of the parent relative box (which is 10px left of it's natural spot).

I didn't see a third question. The bounding box might be hard to find since it is a span which has display inline mixed with the absolute positioning.

Comment: So the parent realtive box is the block box of <p>?

Comment: @user132522 yes, if you look up the dom tree, it's the first parent of the element that has position:relative so it should be the element which the span's absolute position is relative to